# Merge Static Frameworks into a single dynamic framework

Tags: xcode, carthage

I'm currently using Carthage as a dependency manager to download some frameworks, these frameworks are the following Alamofire, ObjectMapper & Result. Then I use a script that builds each framework target as a static framework using the following project config. You can see the script below.

```
xcconfig=$(mktemp /tmp/static.xcconfig.XXXXXX)
trap 'rm -f "$xcconfig"' INT TERM HUP EXIT

echo "LD = $PWD/./ld.py" >> $xcconfig
echo "ARCHS = x86_64 i386 arm64 armv7 armv7s" >> $xcconfig
echo "DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf" >> $xcconfig
echo "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0" >> $xcconfig
echo "ENABLE_BITCODE = NO" >> $xcconfig

export XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE="$xcconfig"

carthage build "$@"
```

This is fine and outputs the following when I want to check if the framework is truly static.

```
Alamofire: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures: [arm_v7:current ar archive] [arm64]
Alamofire (for architecture armv7): current ar archive
Alamofire (for architecture armv7s):    current ar archive
Alamofire (for architecture i386):  current ar archive
Alamofire (for architecture x86_64):    current ar archive
Alamofire (for architecture arm64): current ar archive
```

So I've been following the [guide](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/StaticFrameworks.md) on Carthage on how to combine Static frameworks into a larger Dynamic framework so that I can distribute a framework with Alamofire, ObjectMapper & Result, this takes away the responsibility from the developer.

But after following the steps I seem to be getting the following error whenever I try to build or archive the project and link my new dynamic framework.

```
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Testing Frameworks/Valid Frameworks/MyDependencies.framework' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I resolve this and merge static frameworks into a dynamic one so that the third parties are always available during build/run time as well as when I distribute the framework.